# Windows PC starting up and opens "Choose an Option" screen

Tags: windows-10, boot, troubleshooting

I booted my PC and this screen opened.

[image: The choose an option screen]

Under Troubleshoot --> Advanced Options, I selected Startup Repair and the PC did a little repairing process but the problem is yet not solved. If anyone knows a solution to this it'll be really helpful.

I tried Googling for a solution but could find an answer to this. I also tried the first option shown above (Continue) but that only restarts the PC and brings it back to this screen again.

I found people asking the same question but none has working solutions.

Comment: Try to use `dism` and `sfc` from a USB WinPE stick, they may or may not solve your problem, if they don't help, then I am afraid there is only one way to solve your problem: a clean reinstallation of Windows. Backup all important information(if any) before reinstallation.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Troubleshoot again. See if you can get into Safe Mode with Networking. If so, try running a Windows 10 Repair Install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.
>
> Start with the option to Keep Everything.
>
> You can also Keep Data, or Keep Nothing. Keep Nothing is very close to
> a clean install.

This might work and might not work.

If no, make a Bootable USB key from the Windows 10 ISO.  Start with that, start a terminal session and see if you can see the main drive or any data on it.

It appears the main drive has an error. If you are lucky, you can format it and install Windows fresh.